# Problems with the Android Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I found this Question multiple times but none of the Solutions seemed to work.

I have the following in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".noactivity.Airplane">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And the following class:

```
public class Airplane extends BroadcastReceiver {

public Airplane(){
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("AirplaneMode", "Service state changed");
    Toast.makeText(context,"Airplane mode changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

But if I change the Airplane mode nothing happens. To be sure I also added:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    registerReceiver(new Airplane(), new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED"));
}}
```

What also didn't work.
Do any of you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this successfully without adding the receiver in manifest.
In you activity add this:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {

    //register receiver for air plane mode states
    IntentFilter airPlaneModeFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(airPlaneModeReceiver, airPlaneModeFilter);

    super.onResume();
}

private BroadcastReceiver airPlaneModeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean airPlaneModeEnabled = intent.getBooleanExtra("state", false);
        if (airPlaneModeEnabled) {

} else {

}
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (airPlaneModeReceiver != null) unregisterReceiver(airPlaneModeReceiver);

    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Great happy to help :D